# Is this a bug in TS? (interpolated esliteral not being treated as a string type)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TS seems to think the type of interpolated prop values like:

```
{ href: `#234${undefined}2213` }
```

are NOT strings (when they're used inside a discriminated union)?

The third `p3` instance below loses type inference for the `ev` field, but only when the href is an interpolated esliteral string.

```
type BiomePlainLinkProps = {
  href: string;
  onClick?: (event: string) => void;
}

type BiomeButtonProps = {
  href?: never;
  onClick?: (event: number) => void;
}

export type ClickableDiscriminatedUnion =
  | BiomePlainLinkProps
  | BiomeButtonProps;

const p1: ClickableDiscriminatedUnion = {
  href: '2332132',
  onClick: (ev) => console.log('@@@@', ev), // ev is string here
}

const p2: ClickableDiscriminatedUnion = {
  onClick: (ev) => console.log('@@@@', ev), // ev is number here
}

const p3: ClickableDiscriminatedUnion = {
  href: `2${undefined}332132`,
  onClick: (ev) => console.log('@@@@', ev), // ev is any (not string) here
}
```

[TS sandbox full repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQglgewLYQAoBsCGcB2AZXAa1QCcEwBnKAXigG8AoKKACxIgDMAuKC4E3AHMA3EygIcAYXRwAxoQD8PABQQAbhBzAefATkEBKGgD4oahHAAmogL4MGoSLEQoYAV2DAJpclVqNmNk4lKBx1CBJRZglpOUUVcK0eHDckACMIo2pTcytbewgADzAEEmAoR2hY+Uw09AgAETgKWQEkXExgCEsAVRxEHBoxAB9nZDQsXAIcYjJKEbHXDy8cH0pRBlkJPigwAEYeasJa+qaWto6u3v6JGnoxIO4oAHIAJgBmd9e9r+eAGjEMRk8gSaiypi2OAoCHqADp0AhBMpngABNEo-5QdQGP5QAD0eKxaigzV4-CErAiEAYdk223KYFeh2BxzqjWarTg7RwnW6fQGdwC4ikLNB4KgkOhcIRSNR6Mx2NxBKJJKoKXSEUp7Bp9klDPezLiJ3Z5y5lz5N0G-ge7CeAANXgASOhuHCWTi4bo2T7fL52gHREVxMUmCXbGEQeGI5HojG4xX4wnqVVQTA4EBQZQ4BDldUZEhGFhUmlAA)

Comment: Are you sure that your 113 line example is a [mcve]? By the way, when I hover the property in the playground, it shows me that the type is `string`, so this doesn't seem to reproduce your issue anyway.

Comment: Amended question by adding some of the code from the code sandbox

Comment: There's plenty of context here to understand what is being asked...

Comment: @JeffMercado The problem is not lack of context, the problem is lack of a [mcve]. The question asks why the `href` property is not a string, yet the example shows that property being a string; and the example is over a hundred lines of code, which is certainly not minimal.

Comment: OK, i've just included the entire sandbox code example.

Comment: Of course you can trim the example down; [here](https://tsplay.dev/w8X2Ew) is the result of a minute or two's work trimming it down.  It could surely be trimmed down more.

Comment: Hmmm, might be a problem with the compiler or config? Same problem if you 
declare an object directly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYk1z.png

Comment: [Here it is in six lines](https://tsplay.dev/wR0VXm).  I'd replace with this.

Comment: Thanks all. Ive amended the sample code and repo links.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a TypeScript limitation, where you have a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) value whose discriminant property's type is evaluated too late. It's the same behavior as in [this example](https://tsplay.dev/WoYn8N).  Still looking for relevant GitHub issues.

Comment: Eh I haven't found anything definitely relevant; [ms/TS#53033](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53033) is the closest, but `\`${"x"}\`` isn't "context-sensitive" the way `v => v` is, so it's not quite the same.  I need to disengage for the night; if nobody finds anything more appropriate I'll continue looking tomorrow, but or maybe open an issue to get an official word on the matter.

Comment: I still haven't found anything.  I suppose I'll open an GitHub issue unless @glo wants to do it

Comment: @jcalz hey dude. Sorry for the delayed response, today's been nuts. :P I'd be very happy for you to open the issue (if you're willing), and I can chime in. I've never filed a ts github issue before, it looks... daunting. 


i've bounced your six line example around at work, and we've found ways around it (using an intersection type instead of a union for example) - but such work arounds are going to take a lot of refactor to apply - So i'm kinda hoping that this is actually a TS bug with union types.

Comment: Okay I just filed [ms/TS#53888](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53888) and will write an answer here when I see what they say about it.  In terms of workarounds, surely you could just compute your interpolated string into a `const` ahead of time and use it later, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NB8rxW) or [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbvD9m); I imagine it's a bit annoying to do that with JSX but at least it's possible.  (That is out of scope for the question as asked though so I won't go into that when I answer)

Comment: Okay they've classified it as a TS bug and it's listed as "help wanted" so if you really want to see it fixed they're accepting PRs for it.  I'll write up an answer here when I get a chance.

Comment: Oh man! I didn’t think of that work around. That’s totally doable. Thank you kindly @jcalz for all the help. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** for TS5.2+

This bug has been fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#53907](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53907), so starting with TypeScript 5.2, the code in the question will work as desired with no changes necessary.

[Playground link to code using TS 5.2.0-dev.20230516](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.0-dev.20230516#code/C4TwDgpgBAQglgewLYQAoBsCGcB2AZXAa1QCcEwBnKAXigG8AoKKACxIgDMAuKC4E3AHMA3EygIcAYXRwAxoQD8PABQQAbhBzAefATkEBKGgD4oahHAAmogL4MGoSLEQoYAV2DAJpclVqNmNk4lKBx1CBJRZglpOUUVcK0eHDckACMIo2pTcytbewgADzAEEmAoR2hY+Uw09AgAETgKWQEkXExgCEsAVRxEHBoxAB9nZDQsXAIcYjJKEbHXDy8cH0pRBlkJPigwAEYeasJa+qaWto6u3v6JGnoxIO4oAHIAJgBmd9e9r+eAGjEMRk8gSaiypi2OAoCHqADp0AhBMpngABNEo-5QdQGP5QAD0eKxaigzV4-CErAiEAYdk223KYFeh2BxzqjWarTg7RwnW6fQGdwC4ikLNB4KgkOhcIRSNR6Mx2NxBKJJKoKXSEUp7Bp9klDPezLiJ3Z5y5lz5N0G-ge7CeAANXgASOhuHCWTi4bo2T7fL52gHREVxMUmCXbGEQeGI5HojG4xX4wnqVVkvSCLXQQC8G4BZHZpQA)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** for TS5.1-

It turns out that *yes, this is a bug in TypeScript*, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#53888](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53888) which I filed in response to this Stack Overflow question.  The compiler seems to recognize that the [discriminant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) property `href` is of type `string` as opposed to `undefined`, but this happens too late to [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the `onClick` callback parameter. Presumably [template literal interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation) delays things enough to cause the problem.

The GitHub issue is in [the Backlog](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/29), meaning that the TS team does not plan to fix it anytime soon... but as such it is also marked [Help Wanted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/labels/Help%20Wanted), meaning that they will entertain pull requests from community members; so anyone who wants to see this addressed sooner than later should consider contributing the fix themselves.

In the meantime, the workaround I'd recommend here is just to do your string interpolation ahead of time and store it in a `const`, so that its type is known in advance:

```
const theHref = `2${undefined}332132`;

const p4: ClickableDiscriminatedUnion = {
  href: theHref,
  onClick: (ev) => ev.toUpperCase()  // okay
}
```

It's annoying (probably more so with JSX) but at least it works!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQglgewLYQAoBsCGcB2AZXAa1QCcEwBnKAXigG8AoKKACxIgDMAuKC4E3AHMA3EygIcAYXRwAxoQD8PABQQAbhBzAefATkEBKGgD4oahHAAmogL4MGoSLEQoYAV2DAJpclVqNmNk4lKBx1CBJRZglpOUUVcK0eHDckACMIo2pTcytbewgADzAEEmAoR2hY+Uw09AgAETgKWQEkXExgCEsAVRxEHBoxAB9nZDQsXAIcYjJKEbHXDy8cH0pRBlkJPigwAEYeasJa+qaWto6u3v6JGnoxIO4oAHIAJgBmd9e9r+eAGjEMRk8gSaiypnUADovD0wJASJJMBQIMoDAw7JttuUwK9DsDjnVGs1WnB2jhOt0+gM7gFxFJ8aDwVAoV4AGJwQrdVHo+xbHA7MDvPFxE5E86ky6Um6DfwPdhPAAGrwAJHQ3DhLJxcN0bJ9vl8FQDovS4oyTMy1NCEAANW2oqAAegdzJIZBIPMx-PKwBYEAAEvK7krVerNRxtZZdV8fq8FaI+QKACzCmqEs4kskU67U2WBeU8H3++VGulHM3ZC1W2HwxHI+2O50IY4gdFAA)

Comment: Gah! That workaround will work for us. Thanks again! :D